# Junction between curved and straight edge in KiCAD

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I have a round PCB with a tab that extends outwards for a connector. I am unable to get the outside lines to properly resolve and connect together at the ends.

Here is an image of the complete board and a zoom on the problem area.

[image]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/bhT3wqd.png]

**How can I properly draw the outline so that [the company](http://www.seeedstudio.com/fusion_pcb.html) will accept the file?**

Comment: Yeah, it's really annoying. Moreover, if I were you, I'd put some round fillet between the two shapes to prevent easy breaking of the PCB. So the math then becomes much more complicated. Just use Simon Richter's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty much nontrivial, because snapping to graphics primitives does not work. I'm going to file a bug about this.

For the time being, I think your best bet is drawing the outline in inkscape or some other vector tool, export it as DXF, and import in KiCad into the Edge.Cuts layer.

Comment: I ended up using Solidworks and exporting a drawing to DXF. This worked perfectly. If you'd like, feel free to edit your answer with the following screenshots that show the result: http://imgur.com/a/tJ0uW

Answer (score 6):

It seems that it is not possible to snap to the circle. Eagle has the same difficulty. However the problem can be solved using some relatively trivial maths. Its basically a geometry problem of trying to find the coordinate of where the line intersects the circle, and then setting the XY coordinate of the end of the line equal to that point.

A diagram will help:

[image: Intersection with circle]

You know both the origin coordinates of the circle \$(X_0,Y_0)\$ and also where the line is on the x-axis - the \$X_1\$ part of the coordinate. Finally you also know the radius \$r\$ of the circle. That is all the information required to find \$Y1\$.

From the diagram, we can say that: 
$$\mathrm{d}X = X_0 - X_1 \tag 1$$

From there we can simply use Pythagoras's Theorem:

$$\mathrm{d}Y = \sqrt{r^2 - \mathrm{d}X^2} \tag 2$$

Then:

$$Y_1 = Y_0 + \mathrm{d}Y \tag 3$$

Putting (1) and (2) into (3) it becomes:

$$Y_1 = Y_0 + \sqrt{r^2 - (X_0 - X_1)^2} \tag 4$$

If you solve (4) for each of your two lines, that will give you the y-axis position for the end of each of the lines such that the line ends on the circle.

In Eagle I would then draw an arc which ends on both of those two points. You can work out the total angle of the arc by using trigonometry to get \$\theta\$ for each of the two lines and find that \$\theta_{arc} = 360^\circ - (\theta_1 - \theta_2)\$. That draws an arc that is the correct radius and intersects with the two lines. I assume you can do the same thing in KiCAD.

Comment: I'll also add that KiCad expects a closed polygon for the board outline layer, as do most fabs. Open the section of the circle where the tab is (create an arc instead if you have to), zoom in, and connect the ends if need be. Sometimes you can grab a line or end with the G key; if not, right-click it and enter the coordinates manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar, connecting the end of a curve to a straight line for edge-cuts.

The way I got it to work was:
Draw a reasonably close approximation. Then use 3d-viewer and it will tell you there is an error at the end of the curve (you might have to rotate your drawing so that the error occurs at the end of curve instead of the end of the line). This will give you the coordinates of the end of the curve to 6 decimal places. Change the end point of the line to these coordinates. Now the other end of the line should be 'on the grid'.

TLDR: KiCad's grid system only goes to 6 decimal places and kicad will work out the curve's end point for you.